# R: kable_as_image cannot find Ghostscript

Tags: r, ghostscript, kableextra

I'm re-running some R Markdown scripts that worked fine a month ago, but now kable_as_image is unable to find Ghostscript (yes, I'm on Windows 8). I get the following error message:

```
Error in kable_as_image(criteria.table,"Criteria",file_format="jpeg"): 
Ghostscript is required to read PDF on windows. Please download it here: https://ghostscript.com/
```

My computer still has Ghostscript, which runs fine when I open it up independently (I tried reinstalling Ghostscript; it didn't help). My guess is that the problem has something to do with R, RStudio, or a package being unable to find the Ghostscript.

I'm pretty sure I've upgraded R in the interim, and I'm currently on 3.4.3 with the latest versions of kableExtra and magick. I've also tried

```
Sys.setenv(R_GSCMD="C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.22/bin/gswin64.exe")
```

(and also for gswin64c.exe) but that didn't help, either. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have `C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.22/bin` inside your PATH system environment variable? use `Sys.getenv("PATH")` to see your PATH

Comment: @chinsoon12: No, it's not set in Windows. It used to work fine without that. I tried adding that to PATH from within R `Sys.setenv("PATH"=sprintf("%s;C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs9.22\\bin",Sys.getenv("PATH")))` and it still doesn't find Ghostscript when running individual chunks.

Comment: You need to add that to the path

Comment: I've discovered that knitting the Rmd file works fine -- it's only when I try to run individual code chunks within the Rmd file that I get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite what the error message says, R needs the path to MikTeX (or your TeX program of choice), not to Ghostscript itself. The best solution is to add it to PATH in your operating system directly so it's always there, but it also works to add it within R. This is helpful to test it out before digging into your OS (make sure you have the right path), or if you don't have administrator privileges to your work machine.

```
Sys.setenv("PATH"=sprintf("%s;C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\",Sys.getenv("PATH")))
```

Your path to MikTeX will likely be different than mine. Note that you need `sprintf()` or something similar to *add* the directory to the end of the PATH instead of overwriting the existing path.

Comment: I still have no idea why knitting the Rmd document found MikTeX just fine, while running code chunks needed the PATH to be set properly. If anyone understands this, please let me know!